# I have the error while running 'vagrant up' on my MAC OS

Tags: mac, virtualbox

I installed vagrant_2.3.4_darwin_amd64 and also installed VirtualBox-7.0.6_BETA4-155176-macOSArm64 on my MAC OS ventura 13. My MAC has M2 chip.

I was going to run the 'vagrant up' command but it doesn't work with this error.

```
    The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
    to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
    'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
    properly and try again.
    
    If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
    it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
    GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
    For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
    VirtualBox GUI is open.

The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue.
```

This project was successfully working on my Windows OS. Please help me.

Comment: vagrant_2.3.4_darwin_amd64  is for Intel/amd x86 based CPUs, it's not going to work with the M2 arm cpu...you'll need the arm version of vagrant.

Comment: Hello, @essjae.
Thank you for your response.
I am sorry but what does not working of vagrant mean?
I installed it successfully in my OS.